# How combine two or more files with tags?

Tags: combine, files

#### `file-a.tex`:

```
\tag{a1}

a-blabla.....

\tag{a2}

a-blabla....
```

#### `file-b.tex`:

```
\tag{a1}

b-blabla...

\tag{a2}

b-blabla...

\tag{a3}

b-blabla
```

#### `file-c.tex`:

```
\tag{a2}

c-blabla...

\tag{a1}

c-blabla...
```

#### `all.tex`:

```
\documentclass....

.....

....

\input{file-a}

\input{file-b}

\input{file-c}
```

How can generate ?

> a-blabla.....%from file-a
>
> b-blabla...%from file-b
>
> c-blabla...%from file-c
>
> a-blabla....%from file-a
>
> b-blabla...%from file-b
>
> c-blabla...%from file-c
>
> b-blabla...%from file-b

Comment: did you try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/catchfilebetweentags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your files include (`file1.tex`):

```
\tag{a1}
{a1-blabla..... from file1}

\tag{a2}
{a2-blabla.... from file1}
```

(etc. in other files). Then you can use the following macro:

```
\def\sgdef#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname}
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\long\def\tag#1#2{\expandafter\ifx\csname tag:#1\endcsname \relax
    \sgdef{tag:#1}{#2\par}\else
    \global\expandafter\addto\csname tag:#1\endcsname{#2\par}\fi}

\def\printtag#1{\csname tag:#1\endcsname}

\input file1
\input file2
\input file3

\printtag{a1}
\printtag{a2}
\printtag{a3}
```

This is simple exercise for using `\csname...\endcsname`.

Comment: thanks. good method, where can i find about \csname ... \endcsname usage details ?

Comment: how can i ignore all "\tag{"  and  "}", sometimes i only want to generate a "whole text"

Answer (score 5):

## Solution based on `docstrip`

If the form of the tags are free to choose, then `docstrip` already has this capabilities. A block of code is tagged with `a1` the following way:

```
%<*a1>
... code block ...
%</a1>
```

`%<*a1>` with the star starts the range, and `%</a1>` with the slash is the end tag. If the code block contains lines with comments, which should not be removed by `docstrip`, then guards help:

```
%<*a1>
%<<GUARD
... code block ...
%GUARD
%</a1>
```

Example for `file-a.tex`:

```
%<*a1>
%<<GUARD
File=a, tag a1
%GUARD
%</a1>
%<*a2>
%<<GUARD
File a, tag a2
%GUARD
%</a2>
%<*a3>
%<<GUARD
File a, tag a3
%GUARD
%</a3>
```

Then a driver file `file-all.ins` for `docstrip` is needed:

```
% arara: tex
\input docstrip.tex
\Msg{* Generates file-all.tex from file-a.tex, file-b.tex, file-c.tex}
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\nopreamble
\nopostamble
\generate{
  \file{file-all.tex}{
    \from{file-a.tex}{a1}
    \from{file-b.tex}{a1}
    \from{file-c.tex}{a1}
    \from{file-a.tex}{a2}
    \from{file-b.tex}{a2}
    \from{file-c.tex}{a2}
    \from{file-a.tex}{a3}
    \from{file-b.tex}{a3}
    \from{file-c.tex}{a3}
  }
}
\endbatchfile
```

LaTeX is not needed for compiling the file, plain TeX (or even iniTeX) is sufficient:

```
tex file-all.ins
```

Then `docstrip` writes the file `file-all.tex`:

```
File=a, tag a1
File=b, tag a1
File=c, tag a1
File a, tag a2
File b, tag a2
File c, tag a2
File a, tag a3
File b, tag a3
File c, tag a3
```

Of course, the list of `\from` statements can be automatically calculated, given the file and tag names. The following version of `file-all.ins` uses pgf's `\foreach`, wich can also be used in plain TeX:

```
% arara: tex
\input pgffor.tex
\input docstrip.tex
\Msg{* Generates file-all.tex from file-a.tex, file-b.tex, file-c.tex}
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\nopreamble
\nopostamble

\gdef\fromlist{}
\begingroup
  \let\from\relax
  \foreach \tag in {a1, a2, a3} {
    \foreach \file in {file-a, file-b, file-c} {
       \xdef\fromlist{\fromlist
         \from{\file.tex}{\tag}%
       }
    }
  }
\endgroup

\generate{
  \file{file-all.tex}{\fromlist}
}
\endbatchfile
```

Finally, the file `file-all.tex` is included in the main document, e.g.:

```
\input{file-all}
```

Or if the shell escape feature is enabled, the `docstrip` call can also be embedded in the main document:

```
\immediate\write18{tex file-all}% generate file-all.tex
\input{file-all}
```

Comment: thanks. i think this is a powerful method, but i think i need a little time to learn.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package:

## File `all.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{a1}
\definecollection{a2}
\definecollection{a3}

\begin{document}

\input{a.tex}
\input{b.tex}
\input{c.tex}

\includecollection{a1}
\includecollection{a2}
\includecollection{a3}

\end{document}
```

## File `a.tex`

```
\begin{collect}{a1}{}{}
a-blabla...  in file a.tex
\end{collect}

\begin{collect}{a2}{}{}
a-blabla...  in file a.tex
\end{collect}
```

## File `b.tex`

```
\begin{collect}{a1}{}{}
b-blabla...  in file b.tex
\end{collect}

\begin{collect}{a2}{}{}
b-blabla...  in file b.tex
\end{collect}

\begin{collect}{a3}{}{}
b-blabla...  in file b.tex
\end{collect}
```

## File `c.tex`

```
\begin{collect}{a2}{}{}
c-blabla...  in file c.tex
\end{collect}

\begin{collect}{a1}{}{}
c-blabla... in file c.tex
\end{collect}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: thankss. easy way, i can use it most occasions. but can only use definecollection{xx} 11 times, sometimes i want about use 70 collections, any new hint?