# How to combine two files like this?

Tags: combine, tags, files

I have these codes

a.tex

```
\tag{1.1}{this is 1.1 from file a.}
\tag{1.2}{this is 1.2 from file a.}
```

b.tex

```
\tag{1.1}{this is 1.1 from file b.}
\tag{1.2}{this is 1.2 from file b.}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\somedef... ?
\begin{document}
  \input{a.tex}\\
  \input{b.tex}\\

  \print{a:1.1}\\ % result 1 line

  \print{b:1.2}\\ % result 1 line

  \printa{1.1}\\ % result 2 lines

  \printa{1.2}   % result 2 lines
\end{document}
```

and I hope to get this

```
this is 1.1 from file a. 

this is 1.2 from file b.

this is 1.1 from file a.
this is 1.1 from file b.

this is 1.2 from file a.
this is 1.2 from file b.
```

Comment: why two commands, `\print` and `\printa` and why does `\printa` print the values from file b?

Comment: the last answer from (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266998/how-combine-two-or-more-files-with-tags/267016#267016) solved part of this problem

Comment: \printa means print-all-ignore-file-names

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer since it seems to answer the question that you have asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Important note*: in the code below, `filecontents` is used just for making the examples self-contained.

I store each tag in a property list, with a key of the form

```
<filename>@<tag>
```

and the given value.

The macro `\print` splits its argument at a colon; if the colon is present, the value corresponding to `<filename>@<tag>` is printed (provided it exists); otherwise a loop is performed on all stored filenames.

```
\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
\tag{1.1}{this is 1.1 from file a.}
\tag{1.2}{this is 1.2 from file a.}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{b.tex}
\tag{1.1}{this is 1.1 from file b.}
\tag{1.2}{this is 1.2 from file b.}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\print}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}m}{\printaux#1}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printaux}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \zeno_print_all:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \zeno_print_one:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\taginput}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_zeno_taginput_seq { ##1 }
    \zeno_taginput_file:n { ##1 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_zeno_taginput_seq
\prop_new:N \g_zeno_taginput_data_prop
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { Nx }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \zeno_taginput_file:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__zeno_taginput_current_tl { #1 }
  \file_input:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tag #1 #2
 {
  \prop_gput:Nxn \g_zeno_taginput_data_prop
   { \l__zeno_taginput_current_tl @ #1 }
   { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \zeno_print_one:nn
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_zeno_taginput_data_prop {#1 @ #2 } \par
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \zeno_print_all:n
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_zeno_taginput_seq
   {
    \zeno_print_one:nn { ##1 } { #1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\taginput{a,b}

\print{a:1.1}   % result 1 line

\print{b:1.2}   % result 1 line

\bigskip

\print{1.1}    % result 2 lines

\bigskip

\print{1.2}    % result 2 lines

\end{document}
```

[image]

A “classical” implementation with a slightly different syntax.

```
\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
\tag{1.1}{this is 1.1 from file a.}
\tag{1.2}{this is 1.2 from file a.}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{b.tex}
\tag{1.1}{this is 1.1 from file b.}
\tag{1.2}{this is 1.2 from file b.}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\print}[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \print@all{#2}%
  \else
    \print@one{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\taginput}[1]{%
  \ifx\taginput@files\@empty
    \gdef\taginput@files{#1}%
  \else
    \g@addto@macro\taginput@files{,#1}%
  \fi
  \def\taginput@current{#1}%
  \input{#1}%
}
\let\taginput@files\@empty

\newcommand{\tag}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{taginput@\taginput@current @#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\print@all}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\@for\noexpand\next:=\taginput@files\noexpand\do
  }\x{\print@one{\next}{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\print@one}[2]{%
  \@nameuse{taginput@#1@#2}\par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\taginput{a}
\taginput{b}

\print[a]{1.1}   % result 1 line

\print[b]{1.2}   % result 1 line

\bigskip

\print{1.1}    % result 2 lines

\bigskip

\print{1.2}    % result 2 lines

\end{document}
```

Comment: why i got "

! Undefined control sequence.
\zeno_print_one:nn #1#2->\prop_item:Nn 
                                       \g_zeno_taginput_data_prop {#1@#2}\par 
l.74 \print{a:1.1}
                     % result 1 line
? "  ( i use xelatex )

Comment: and i just update my xparse to "released 2018-10-17"  :_?

Comment: @ZenoShuai Not just `xparse`, but the whole `expl3` bundle, in particular `l3kernel`.

Comment: (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018-12-12 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018-12-12 L3 programming layer (code)


! Package expl3 Error: Required primitives not found." and how to go ... ?

Comment: @ZenoShuai TeX Live 2014? Well, you're doomed.

Comment: You scared me!

sudo tlmgr install --reinstall

i can use most of my code ......

Comment: How to do it like (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266998/how-combine-two-or-more-files-with-tags/267016#267016)  ?

Comment: @ZenoShuai I added an `expl3` free version

Comment: @ egreg at egreg, You really are a great guy, although you scared me to death just now.

Comment: sometimes main.tex contain "\tag{1.1}{this is 1.1 from file main.}", and how can use print[main]{1.1} or print[me]{1.1}, both is better :-)

Comment: and another case, no file_a and file_b ,all tags in main.tex, i get "! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> taginput@\taginput@current 
                                      @cover"

Comment: oh, when some tags in main.tex some output missed ?

Comment: @ZenoShuai Did you ask for tags in the main file?

Comment: yes, @ egreg , thank you very much from yesterday to forever

Comment: @ZenoShuai No, you didn't mention `\tag` in the main file. What order should they appear in?

Comment: @ egreg, In the order it appears

Comment: @ZenoShuai This means nothing, sorry. With `\print` (no optional argument), tags appear by order of input files. Please, open a new question with ***all*** the details. For instance, where do you expect `\taginput` be? Where do you expect `\tag` in the main file to appear? What if `\print` appears *before* the corresponding `\tag` command?

Comment: i change the request, @egreg @ egreg ,can u help me?

Comment: @ZenoShuai No, it doesn't work like that. The answer was doing what you asked for. For an extension, open a new followup question.

Comment: open a new followup question like this: (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467276/how-to-use-main-file-combined-other-two-files-with-tags?noredirect=1#comment1175111_467276) ? @egreg

Comment: BTW, why i can't write "@egreg" at the first words?